# JNI "The specified procedure could not be found" when dependent library is linked

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Following is the basic working structure:

> MainProxy.dll ==> JNIClient.java

Using JNI, I have successfully loaded the MainProxy.dll and able to call the native functions. Following is the required structure:

> Main.dll ==> MainProxy.dll ==> JNIClient.java

But when MainProxy.dll compiled and linked with another DLL Main.dll the System.loadLibrary("MainProxy"); call crashed with an exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: MainProxy.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
```

However, the MainProxy.dll is successfully compiled and linked against Main.lib and both DLLs are placed to gather with java.

Any idea what causes this issue and how it can be resolved?

[image]

Above is the snap from dependencywalker. The ISPVPLPR.dll is the Main.dll and LPRPROXY.DLL is the MainProxy.dll. And the linking between these two looks fine. The CreateNativeClass is exported along with other functions from ISPVPLPR.dll while only CreateNativeClass is imported in LPRPROXY.dll.

[image]

Above snap shows that exported native function from LPRProxy.dll

Comment: From your screenshot it is not clear that the native methods are in LPRPROXY.DLL. Another problem could be that the loader can find LPRPROXY.DLL but not ISPVPLPR.DLL. To be on the safe side, try `System.LoadLibrary("ISPVPLPR")` before the call `System.loadLibrary("LPRPROXY.DLL")`.

Comment: @Alex, I have tried System.LoadLibrary("ISPVPLPR") before System.LoadLibrary("LPRPROXY"), it also gives the same error

The specified procedure could not be found

Comment: The error happens when you load the library or when you call the native method?

Comment: When it loads the DLL.
`static {
   System.out.println("Loading LPRProxy.dll");
   //System.loadLibrary("ISPVPLPR");
   System.loadLibrary("LPRProxy");
   System.out.println("Loading LPRProxy.dll completed.");
    }`  
The statement "Loading LPRProxy.dll completed" never printed and it prints the exception.

Comment: Does `System.loadLibrary("ISPVPLPR")` succeed?

Comment: No, `System.loadLibrary("ISPVPLPR")` also returns the same error, " The specified procedure could not be found"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94830/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-jawad-akhtar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it turns out that OpenCV pre-compiled libraries was the issue. The ISPVPLPR.DLL was utilizing OpenCV and the copied DLLs were the default that came with setup and were compiled for WinXP Prof 64bit or Win2003 64bit. Since Opencv_Core241.dll requires RtlLookupFunctionEntry and RtlVirtualUnwind functions from Kernel32.dll and these functions were only provided for WinXP and Win2003 Kernel32.dll versions ([MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

The solution was simple to recompile the OpenCV2.4.1 for Win7 and with GOD blessings it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Dependency Walker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/256872) from microsoft. Use this utility to really check if `MainProxy.dll` is correctly linked with `Main.dll`.

If Dependency Walker shows you a problem, tell us how do you compiled and linked `MainProxy.dll`.

When Dependency Walker shows you no problem, you won't have anymore an `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`

Comment: I have updated the question with dependencywalker snapshot. The linking looks fine.

Comment: @Jawad, Dependency Walker is clearly telling you that `ispvplpr.dll` is not properly linked with several dll's (those in red), so if this library has linked problems it can't be loaded and thus you got the error described in your question. You have to solve these dependencies.

Comment: The "red" marked files are of OS (Windows) and these are files, not the functions. The correctly linked functions are in Green and Blue colors. The Grayed colors are those that are exported by ISPVPLPR and not imported by the caller (LPRProxy)

Comment: Yes, they are dll from os, but if they appear in red, means that ispvplpr can not find it. That's the problem.